# How to create a generic tool to list and edit the properties of any object? (C#)

Tags: c#, winforms, generics

I am creating an editor for my game as a windows forms project to enter all of the data into the game.
The game includes many different class and struct definitions (eg: Items, Entities, coordinates, Terrains, etc.) And each instance of those things needs to have its properties set in the editor.

Creating a custom tool for every single type of object defined in my code base is too involved. It would take me longer to set up all of those tools than it does to program the game its self. I need to create generic and re-usable tools. So far I have learned to use the "Property Grid" which automatically lets you set any data-type in a given object. (assuming that you give it a "get; set;" access modifier.) But what about reference types and data structures?

I want to make a generic tool to inspect and edit the properties of any object:

1. Can I make a tool that will display an "add" button for any null
   reference type variable in the inspected object?
2. And a "Edit" and "delete" button for any reference type variable
   that is not null in the inspected object?
3. Can the "add" button prompt me to choose from a list any
   non-abstract type that derives from the type of the reference?
4. Can the tool also display a list of "edit" or "delete" nodes and a
   'add' button for any 'List' in the inspected object?
5. And to data type variable need to have a "get; set;" access modifier
   on them for them to turn up in the property grid? Why can't it
   detect any public variable in the inspected object?
6. How do you detect all of the properties of an object? How does the
   property inspector do it?

Comment: You may want to read about reflection. As for your post it is likely a bit too broad for SO.

Comment: This is possible - but a lot of work. You need reflection, recursion (if you want to go deep into the object hierarchy), a good strategy to stop the reflection (that means handling references to parent objects), ... Keep in mind that there meight be objects that doesn't have an parameterless constructor in that case it's harder to create an instance (or use FormatterServices.GetUninitializedObject and risk an invalid object state). That's much work. It needs a lot of experiance in C#.

Comment: @MonoLightTech I still have no idea how an `ExpandoObject` will help. He has an existing object. If he wants to copy all properties to an `ExpandoObject` he needs reflection. But if he has reflection he don't need the `ExpandoObject` anymore. Sorry for my question but how will an `ExpandoObject` will help in this szenario?

Comment: As for questions 5 and 6, PropertyGrid lists all public properties of the objects. See the Remarks section on [this page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.propertygrid(v=vs.110).aspx). Detecting public fields is possible via reflection, but the PropertyGrid doesn't do it (which is probably a design decision). It is a good idea anyway to have your fields encapsulated by properties, not exposing them directly.

Comment: Even after you've figured out how to reflect over an object you still don't have the metadata you need for a good UI e.g. length limits, validation, links to other objects with autocomplete, ...

Comment: @ Ian Mercer - Still, I can create a "bad" UI and rely on the users ability to input valid data. This tool is only intended for in house use. When selecting an enum or choosing from a list of valid derived classes it's hard to go wrong anyway. Also, I can add more detail in specific cases later if I have time for it.